# Setting up an Apache Spark Cluster on Amazon EC2 Using CMD

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, cmd

I am working on my graduation project and It's my first time dealing with spark and EC2 
so I am following the steps in this blog

http://www.supergloo.com/fieldnotes/apache-spark-cluster-amazon-ec2-tutorial/#comment-3843

The problem is he is working on MAC and I don't know how to make these commands work on Windows (CMD).

for example this command
ec2/spark-ec2 –key-pair=courseexample –identity-file=courseexample.pem launch spark-cluster-example

Any Help ?!

Answer (score 0):

try running it in the following way (from the same folder):

```
python -Wdefault "ec2\spark_ec2.py" –key-pair=courseexample –identity-file=courseexample.pem launch spark-cluster-example
```

if you don't know how to open console in windows - just press "Start->Run", type `cmd` and hit enter, then you would need to havigate to your Spark home folder, and execute the above command.

NOTE: I don't currently own a Windows machine, so I haven't tried this command myslef.